# Trying to return bool value returns error on CosmosDb

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a document that looks something like this in CosmosDb:

```
{
   "id": "some-value",
   "cost": 20.5,
   "isAvailable": false
}
```

When I run this query in data explorer on the portal, I get the following error:

```
SELECT VALUE c.isAvailable FROM c WHERE c.id = "some-value"
```

The error reads:

> Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'headers')

If I open the details for the error, I see:

> 11:27 AM Failed to query item for container MainCollection:  Cannot
> set properties of undefined (setting 'headers')
>
> 11: 27 AM Successfully fetched 1 item for container MainCollection

Any idea why?

Comment: I imagine this is a client side issue in the browser. I see the same in the emulator but I do see the result being returned in Fiddler - possibly some client side javascript is getting confused when the result is just a scalar value and is "falsy"

Comment: I went ahead and made this request through my API and I do get the actual value fine. I think you're right that it has something to do with the browser based data explorer in the portal.

Comment: And also the issue doesn't occur with `VALUE c.isAvailable` if the isAvailable being returned is `true` and does also occur with `VALUE c.cost` if that is `0` so I think it can't handle scalar values that javascript would regard as falsy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an error in the clientside javascript rather than with the CosmosDB service itself.

It contains the following code (in FetchResult.js)

```
    if (feedResponse) {
        this.feedResponse = feedResponse;
        this.fetchResultType = FetchResultType.Result;
    }
    else {
        this.error = error;
        this.fetchResultType = FetchResultType.Exception;
    }
```

When you select a scalar value then the "feedResponse" is just that value (e.g. `20.5` for cost)

In the event "feedResponse" is the scalar value "false" or "0" this is "[falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)" so it goes through to the `else` branch and the result is counted as an exception rather than being just the legitimate response of the query.

The error message that is eventually returned ("Cannot set properties of undefined") is because of code that expects results of type `FetchResultType.Exception` to have a not null `error` object and so the following fails

```
fetchResult.error.headers = this._getAndResetActiveResponseHeaders();
```

Answer (score 0):

As answered already this looks to be an issue with javascript that is being tracked [here](https://github.com/Azure/cosmos-explorer/issues/176), it seems to be an issue where your isAvailable boolean may actually be `null` or even `undefined` in some cases.

As a stop gap I believe you can edit your query to exclude `NULL` values.

```
SELECT VALUE c.isAvailable 
FROM c 
WHERE c.id = "some-value" 
and ISNULL(c.isAvailable) = false
```